# How to compute quickly the Jordan normal form of a product of the form $B A \operatorname{adj} B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, similar-matrices

> Compute the Jordan normal form of the product $$BA\operatorname{adj}(B),$$ where
> $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 
> 1 & 3 & -1 \\
> -1 & 4 & 0 \\
> 0 & -1 & 4 \\
> \end{pmatrix}, \qquad
> B = \begin{pmatrix} 
> 2 & 1 & 3 \\
> 4 & 0 & 2 \\
> 1 & 1 & 3 \\
> \end{pmatrix}$$

I tried to solve it head-on but it looks that it's a wrong way since $BA\operatorname{adj} B$ is too complicated to compute a JNF. Then I was thinking about computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$, rewrote $BA\operatorname{adj}B$ as $detB*B*A*B^{-1}$ and tried to prove that since $A$ and $B$ have $n$ independent eigenvectors, JNF should $3$ $1x1$ blocks. However, $A$ doesn't have $n$ independent eigenvectors (see below) and I don't really believe it's a correct approach.

$p(\lambda) = - \lambda ^3 + 9 \lambda ^2- 27\lambda + 27 = -( \lambda -3)^3 = 0$

$(A- 3 I)x=0$ is satisfied only for $x=(1,1,1)$

Comment: In order to know JNF of     $(\det B)BAB^{-1},$ you just need to calculate $\det B$ and JNF of $A$

Comment: You wrote "However, A don't have n eigenvectors". Please edit your post to include your calculations.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the post and included calculations. Can you please elaborate why I need to calculate only $detB$ and JNF of A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Computing gives $\det B \neq 0$, so $\operatorname{adj} B = (\det B) B^{-1},$ and thus
$$B A \operatorname{adj} B = B ((\det B) A) B^{-1} \sim (\det B) A,$$ where you've essentially already found the equality. In particular, $B A \operatorname{adj} B$ and $(\det B) A$ have the same Jordan normal form.

Now, for a (nonzero) scalar $\mu$, how can we express the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of $\mu A$ in terms of those of $A$?

Comment: Thank you. I believe constant $\mu$ only changes eigenvalues to $\mu * \lambda$ and doesn't affect eigenvectors? Since $\mu A v= \mu \lambda v$. Am I right?

Comment: Correct on both counts: First, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\lambda I - A$ is singular $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mu(\lambda I - A)) = (\mu \lambda) I - \mu A$ is singular $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mu \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\mu A$. Second, if $A v = \lambda v$, then $(\mu A) v = \mu (A v) = \mu (\lambda v) = (\mu \lambda) v$.

Comment: These facts apply to any square matrix $A$, so if the Jordan normal form of some matrix $A$ is $\bigoplus_{k=1}^m J_{i_k}(\lambda_k)$, the Jordan normal form of $\mu C$ (for $\mu \neq 0$) is $\bigoplus_{k=1}^m J_{i_k}(\mu \lambda_k)$, and the (generalized) $\lambda_k$-eigenvectors of $A$ are the (generalized) $\mu\lambda_k$-eigenvectors of $\mu A$, and vice versa.